# What could be causing meshes to generate rotated? LWGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, chunks, procedural-generation

I am loading chunk values from a height map to create infinite terrain, but I'm having issues with the rendering of each mesh chunk. When I load a single 500x500 unit mesh, it is a smooth mesh. When I load a 5x5 of 100x100 meshes, it is a jumbled up mess.

I made the two different types of meshes save an image of the height of each mesh, and they both give a smooth height map with gradual value changes.

...But when I render them, this is what I see:
[500x500 mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqCbZ.png)
[5x5 100x100 mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEhwQ.png)

As you can see, the 5x5 mesh isn't at all aligned. The first three chunks 0:0, 0:1, and 1:0 seem to look correct, but the others are all different. All rotations in their transformation matrix is vec3(0,0,0), but they generate like this. Here is the code used to render them:

```
    public void render() {
        shader.start();
        shader.loadViewMatrix(Maths.createViewMatrix(engine.getPlayer()));
        shader.loadLight(engine.getManagers().getLightManager().getLights().get(0));

        for(Chunk chunk : engine.getManagers().getTerrainManager().getLoadedChunks().values()) {
            RawModel model = chunk.getModel();

            bindChunk(chunk);
            loadShaderUniforms(chunk);
            GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

            unbindChunk();
        }
        shader.stop();
    }

    private void bindChunk(Chunk chunk) {
        RawModel rawModel = chunk.getModel();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(rawModel.getVaoID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // position
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // textureCoordinates
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // normal

        ModelTexture texture = chunk.getTexture();
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());
    }

    private void unbindChunk() {
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    }

    private void loadShaderUniforms(Chunk chunk) {
        Matrix4f transformation = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(chunk.getLocation().getPosition(),
                chunk.getLocation().getRotation(), 1, true);
        System.out.println(chunk.getLocation().getRotation());
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transformation);
        shader.setShowHeightMap(chunk.shouldShowHeightMap());
    }
```

I'm not familiar with the details of how LWJGL uses VAOs, so it might be a simple issue I'm forgetting. Any help would be appreciated as I've spent several days just narrowing down the issue to a rendering problem instead of a problem with the perlin noise/mesh generation.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, when generating the meshes, are you sure the sampling coordinates for each vertices are right ? What we see rendered is the texture on the objects, or do you simply associate a color to your vertex height ?

Comment: The mesh "texture" is based on the world position. It's just a simple `out_Color=vec4(vec3(worldPosition.y/16), 1.0)` to visualize the height maps. It's divided by 16 as the noise is a range of 0-16.

Comment: Ok, and to create the meshes, how do you sample the noise for each vertex ? Maybe there is an issue here that creates a rotated mesh ? Also when you load shader uniforms, just to be sure can you set the rotation to identity ?

Comment: Toggling setIdentity() didn't appear to change anything, but I added a directional texture instead of creating it via a heightmap. Alk directions were identical. It seems it's not a rotating issue? I'm incredibly confused about what it could possibly be as the heightmap image generated from the chunk generation is still a perfectly smooth transition.

Comment: I narrowed it down. I added a custom height map, and it is very clear that it is loading the map fine and saving an identical version of it. But, it doesn't render it anything like the image.

Comment: Check how you associate each height to each vertex. You can also use renderdoc to see how each VAO looks

Comment: What should I be checking? Each chunk agrees on the height value of any particular point. It also has a smooth transition of height when I take only the Z values of X=0. I'm also not sure how to use RenderDocs with jar files. How could it help?

Comment: It seems that you build the meshes from a texture, and when you display the meshes without any kind of rotation they seems to have random quartor rotations. So my best guess is that the mesh gets the right values, but the order you get them in is wrong so it creates a rotated mesh.
About renderdoc you can simply launch your java program from renderdoc, and then you can capture frames. it's something like javac C:/pathToProgram

Comment: I do specify a rotation. They each have a vec3(0,0,0) rotation applied to their transformation matrix that works just fine for entities.. Sorry if I implied otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue! There was a flaw in how I created the mesh which caused it to render the triangles flipped over. I discovered this by turning off culling and observing it from both sides and moving the three vertex coordinates around. Fixing the vertex face (e.g. swapping it from a clockwise to counter-clockwise and then reversing the X and Z coordinates) fixed it.